# How do I extract the estimation parameters (theta) from GaussianProcessClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, gaussian

```
# Scale/ Normalize Independent Variables 
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X) 
#Split data into train an test set at 50% each
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5, random_state=42) 
gpc= GaussianProcessClassifier(1.0 * RBF(1.0), n_jobs=-1)
gpc.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_proba=gpc.predict_proba(X_test)
#classify as 1 if prediction probablity greater than 15.8%
y_pred = [1 if x >= .158 else 0 for x in y_proba[:, 1]]
```

The above code runs as expected. However, in order to explain the model, something like, 'a 1 unit change in Beta1 will result in a .7% improvement in probability of sucess' , I need to be able to see the theta. How do I do this?
Thanks for the assist. BTW, this is for a homework assignment

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Answer (score 2):

### Very nice question. You can indeed access the `thetas` however in the documentation it is not clear how to do this.

---

Use the following. Here I use the `iris` dataset.

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Scale/ Normalize Independent Variables 
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X) 

#Split data into train an test set at 50% each
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= .5, random_state=42) 

gpc= GaussianProcessClassifier(1.0 * RBF(1.0), n_jobs=-1)
gpc.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_proba=gpc.predict_proba(X_test)

#classify as 1 if prediction probablity greater than 15.8%
y_pred = [1 if x >= .158 else 0 for x in y_proba[:, 1]]

# thetas
gpc.kernel_.theta
```

---

**Results:**

```
array([7.1292252 , 1.35355145, 5.54106817, 0.61431805, 7.00063873,
       1.3175175 ])
```

---

An example from the documentation that access `thetas` can be found [HERE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-gpc-py)

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the `theta` value you are looking for is a property of the kernel object that you pass into the classifier. You can read more [in this section of the sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gaussian-process-kernel-api). You can access the log-transformed values of theta for the classifier kernel by using `classifier.kernel_.theta` where `classifier` is the name of your classifier object.

Note that the [kernel object](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Kernel.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Kernel) also has a method `clone_with_theta(theta)` that might come in handy if you're making modifications to theta.